# Why is measuring half life or oscillation in 2 different gravitational potential well a valid proof of time dilation?

Tags: relativity, time-dilation

It is often quoted that if one measure the rate of radioactive decay or oscillation in high gravitational field and low gravitational field the rate of radioactive decay or oscillation in high gravitational field will be slower than one of the low gravitational field.

This is use as a proof for gravitational time dilation. Since time is perceived to be running slower in high gravitation field as the current definition of time is bound to the oscillation of some atom.

However I cannot wrap my head around this, since it is possible that gravity merely effects the oscillation or radioactive decay process of an atom itself and not the concept of time.

How does scientist know that time is slowed and not the process itself?

Answer (score 0):

"When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth."

The experiments you mentioned were conducted to see if the theory works or fail in those conditions. The results matched the predictions.

Let's do the opposite, keep time consistent and then change the process and subprocess parameters to ensure the results match the experiments. But then for each experiment, you will not be able to predict anything and only after analyzing the data of the experiment would you be able to find what parameters to adjust in other to make the math works if we keep the time consistent. But all those theories would be the most useless theories. Theories that cannot predict are just adjusted statements.

Simple answer: Because Math checks out and it is easy. It is easy to say, time is gonna slow down if you move fast so take that into account no matter what you do.